# CSPack and CSRun for running site in azure emulator from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, psake

I have spend some time trying to get the cspack and csrun command working to run a website locally in the azure emulator.
So far this is what I get, but its not working
I use psake

```
Task StartAzureEmulator { 
& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\bin\cspack' sitename.azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef /out:Sitename.csx /role:sitename;sitename /sites:Vola;Web;Web /copyOnly
& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun' sitename.csx sitename.Azure\ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg /useiisexpress /launchbrowser
}
```

Basically I am not very impressed with how the azure commandline tools works with powershell.
Has anyone got example of this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell the `;` character is a statement separator.  You can escape it by preceding it with a backtick or if you are V3 or higher you can user `--%` to switch PowerShell into a simpler (dumber) parser mode.  Try this:

```
Task StartAzureEmulator { 
    & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\bin\cspack' --% sitename.azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef /out:Sitename.csx /role:sitename;sitename /sites:Vola;Web;Web /copyOnly
    & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun' --% sitename.csx sitename.Azure\ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg /useiisexpress /launchbrowser
}
```

Comment: I thought it had to do with the seperator - thanks will try it out and accept if it works